# Error with running ReactJS/TailwindCSS/Heroku: React Refresh runtime should not be included in the production bundle

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

Working on a webfolio in ReactJS using TailwindCSS. Deployed it to Heroku, builds successfully, but opening the App always gives the error:
ERROR: React Refresh runtime should not be included in the production bundle.

Really not sure what I could've done wrong other than not configure tailwindcss to be deployable. I don't have any devdependencies, they're all dependencies.

package.json:

```
  "name": "webfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post code while asking the question.  In this case here you can post the `package.json` file.

Comment: ```package.json``` has been added

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error right now, I know this post is few months old but still here is my solution :

Under heroku app> settings >Webpack

- Add this
  https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

And on next push or deploying again will make it work. At least it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

[Using craco with create-react-app in production on heroku fails #233](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues/233#issuecomment-757575452)

I added a **server.js** file and changed the **"start"** script to **"node server.js"** in package.json

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the package.json scripts, since it has been renamed to CRACO by tailwind.

`"start": "node server.js"`

Comment: Yes, my start, build and test use craco like so:
```"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },``` but maybe heroku has an error with craco?

Comment: yes i change mine from "start": "craco start" to "start": "node server.js"

and it works on my case.

Comment: can you deploy a create-react-app with tailwindcss without nodeJS and server.js?

Comment: on netlify or github yes, on heroku not yet

Comment: So we can’t deploy tailwind on heroku