# Deploying React App to Heroku "FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment

I've encountered a problem that I think I understand the solution (paying for more bandwidth on Heroku), but I do not understand the origin of the problem and it is driving me crazy. I would appreciate it if anyone can help me figure it out! Hopefully, others that are in a similar situation in the future can refer back to this.

I'm encountering this error which is similar to this error here:
[Heroku server crashes with "JavaScript heap out of memory" when deploying 'react-admin' app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205530/heroku-server-crashes-with-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-when-deploying-react)

I understand that the free tier of Heroku limits me to around 512 MB of memory, and I've set my Heroku config node options like this:

`NODE_OPTIONS:       --max_old_space_size=5120`

All being said and done, I ran my application locally and inspected the memory heap which only uses up a maximum of 20 MB of memory. Weird. It's nothing close to the 512 MB limit Heroku imposes on me?!

What tidbit of information am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and installed the server library with this command in terminal:

`npm i --save serve`

and then changed some of the lines in my package.json file to under the "scripts" section.

```
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Hope this works for you